# Compute the $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{cos(z)}{z^2-2z-3} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to compute  $$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{cos(z)}{z^2-2z-3} dz $$
I tried to work it out with the Cauchy–Goursat theorem but the function has a singularity at $z=-1 $ which is an interior point of my contour $ C: |z|=2$. 
How can I deal with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the Residue theorem?

Comment: No. It is all about the minterm examination I am about to take on complex analysis and we haven't reached that point yet.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: nope, we stopped in the Cauchy-Goursat. However, since Cauchy's integral formula is the next section I took a look and still it requires the function to be analytic in the interior of the contour, so if I see it right the problem remains.

Comment: no you most definetely can use Cauchy's integration formula to solve this

Comment: Hint: apply Cauchy-Goursat to the analytical function $\frac{\cos(z)-\cos(-1)}{z^2-2z-3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{\cos z}{z^2-2z-3}dz = \int_{|z|=2}\frac{\frac{\cos z}{z-3}}{z+1}dz = 2\pi i \frac{\cos(-1)}{-1-3}$$$$=-\frac{\pi}2 i \cos 1 $$
That's just an application of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).